# How to access element of DataTemplate inside of ContentTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

In project I have .xaml like below:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ToolBarItem" x:Key = "LayerToolBar">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <MenuToggleButton x:Name="foregroundbutton">
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <ToolBarItem Style="{DynamicResource LayerToolBar}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Question is how do I access "foregroundbutton" in the code-behind file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically access elements defined in a ContentTemplate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366549/how-can-i-programmatically-access-elements-defined-in-a-contenttemplate)

Comment: traverse the object (style property) from code behind, you will find a way.

Comment: What I am doing now is `Style style = this.Resources["LayerToolBar"] as Style;`, but what should I do next?

Comment: Do you want to access the visible `MenuToggleButton ` of the applied template or the `MenuToggleButton` element inside the template? Or simpler question: what do you plan to do with the element when you access it? Maybe it can be archieved without code behind access.

Comment: The visible one, because i will need to change some of its properties

Comment: Most probably, the properties can be changed in XAML with some triggers - no need to get into code behind. But you are not very specific yet on what you want to happen.

Comment: I have come up with `Loaded="MenuToggleButton_Loaded` and then using sender. Thanks for answers!